# writing/reading number of bytes to/from socket data in Dart

Tags: sockets, dart

In the following server/client socket code, the server tries to send ints from 0 to 1023. The client receives the right number of ints but they wrap at 255. Why is this and what is the proper way?

#### *** Server ***

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  final server = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  server.listen((Socket socket) {
    print('Got connected ${socket.remoteAddress}');
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
      socket.add([i]);
    }
    socket.close();
    print('Closed ${socket.remoteAddress}');
  });
}
```

#### *** Client ***

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

main() async {
  final client = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  client.listen(
      (var data) => print('Got $data'),
      onDone: () { print('Done'); client.close(); },
      onError: (e) { print('Got error $e'); client.close(); });
  print('main done');
}
```

Also, it feels like the Socket api is a bit different - being more Dartish than other languages the way it supports reading as a stream. But what if you just want to read *N* bytes? How do you achieve that? I see the *take* method (*Stream take(int count)*) but I'm not clear on what exactly *count* is taking, especially in terms of how many bytes have been read. Because Socket implements *Stream< List < int > >* and because int is not really a fixed size entity (I think??), how do you know how many bytes have been read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me, I'm not sure this is the most elegant solution

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

main() async {
  final server = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  server.listen((Socket socket) {
    print('Got connected ${socket.remoteAddress}');

    var toByte = new StreamTransformer<List<int>, Uint8List>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: (data, sink) {
      sink.add(new Uint64List.fromList(data).buffer.asUint8List());
    });

    var streamController = new StreamController<List<int>>();
    streamController.stream.transform(toByte).pipe(socket);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
      streamController.add([i]);
    }
    streamController.close();
    print('Closed ${socket.remoteAddress}');
  });
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

main() async {
  final Socket client = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 4041);

  var fromByte = new StreamTransformer<List<int>, List<int>>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (data, sink) {
    sink.add(data.buffer.asInt64List());
  });

  client.transform(fromByte).listen((e) => e.forEach(print));
  print('main done');
}
```

**Original attempt:**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

main() async {
  final server = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  server.listen((Socket socket) {
    print('Got connected ${socket.remoteAddress}');
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
      socket.add(new Uint64List.fromList([i]).buffer.asUint8List());
    }
    socket.close();
    print('Closed ${socket.remoteAddress}');
  });
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

main() async {
  final Socket client = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  client.listen(
      (var data) {
        var ints = new Uint8List.fromList(data).buffer.asInt64List();
        ints.forEach((i) => print('Got $i'));
      },
      onDone: () { print('Done'); client.close(); },
      onError: (e) { print('Got error $e'); client.close(); });
  print('main done');
}
```

If you don't need the range of an Int64 you can also use Int32, Int16 or some of the UIntXX types or whatever fits your value range best, to save some redundantly transmitted 0-bytes.

I have the suspicion that using a converter like it's explained here https://www.dartlang.org/articles/converters-and-codecs/ could be used to do it more elegantly. This seems similar https://gist.github.com/xxgreg/9104926 but I have to admit that I'm not able to apply these examples for your use case.

**Update**

I got it working like shown in the articles linked above

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class IntConverter extends Converter<List<int>, List<int>> {
  const IntConverter();

  List<int> convert(List<int> data) {
    if (data is Uint8List) {
      return data.buffer.asInt64List();
    } else {
      return new Uint64List.fromList(data).buffer.asUint8List();
    }
  }

  IntSink startChunkedConversion(sink) {
    return new IntSink(sink);
  }
}

class IntSink extends ChunkedConversionSink<List<int>> {
  final _converter;
  // fales when this type is used
  // final ChunkedConversionSink<List<int>> _outSink;
  final _outSink;

  IntSink(this._outSink) : _converter = new IntConverter();

  void add(List<int> data) {
    _outSink.add(_converter.convert(data));
  }

  void close() {
    _outSink.close();
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

main() async {
  final server = await ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  server.listen((Socket socket) {
    print('Got connected ${socket.remoteAddress}');

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
      socket.add(new Uint64List.fromList([i]).buffer.asUint8List());
    }
    socket.close();
    print('Closed ${socket.remoteAddress}');
  });
}
```

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'byte_converter.dart';

main() async {
  final Socket client = await Socket.connect('127.0.0.1', 4041);
  client.transform(new IntConverter()).listen((e) => e.forEach(print));
  print('main done');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. I guess a fundamental follow up would be why have socket implement something like *Stream<List<int>>* as it is not clear what is going on since int has a hierarchy. But *Stream< ByteArray >* is clear that it is leaving it to the higher layer to interpret some number of bytes. Also, how do you read n bytes from the socket? It seems buffering is inherent and from logging I see the number of elements in the data is indeterminate.

Comment: I guess it should be `Stream<Uint8List>` to be explicit and avoid ambiguity. Hopefully we get some additional info from LRHN when he sees the question.

Comment: Uint8List is in dart:typed_data, I'm guessing that don't want to introduce a dependency in dart:io. If Dart fully implements typedef, then it would be possible to "typedef byte int;", and then it would become a Stream<List<byte>>. I kind of like the composable nature of Streams and Lists, so I'm not sure if I like "typedef ByteStream Stream<List<int>>;", which would be another way to do the same.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Is it safe to assume that the chunks passed to IntConverter.convert() are always a multiple of 8?

Comment: @GregLowe I'm not sure I fully understand your question. It depends on the type you use. If I'd use Uint32List it would insert 4 bytes per int instead of 8.

Comment: The numbers are converted to binary and sent over the network. The network layer splits the binary into packets of some arbitrary size, then receiving software gets packets from the network layer the size of which depends on the operating systems networking implementation. What happens if the network decides to chop up data the data into packets of size 1500 bytes, which is not a multiple of 8? You'll get half of a int64 in one packet, and then the other half in the next packet. Your IntConverter class doesn't handle this correctly.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: only client side (the last part) how to catch connection error, data error etc...?

Comment: You can use `try{ for(var e in client.transform(new IntConverter())) { ... } } catch(e) {...}` or `.listen((e) {...}, onError: (e) { ... });`

Answer (score 5):

One thing to make clear is that even though most methods in `dart:io` operate on `List<int>` the *underlying assumption* for all IO in Dart is that these lists are list of byte values. The documentation it probably not that precise about that.

This means that you can use whatever `List` implementation you like when sending bytes - including typed data, e.g.

```dart
var socket = ...
socket.add([1, 2, 3]);
socket.add(new List<int>.generate(3, (int index) => index * index);
socket.add('ASCII'.codeUnits);
socket.add(UTF8.encode('Søren'));

var typedData = new Uint8List(8);
var data = new ByteData.view(typedData.buffer);
data.setInt32(0, 256 * 256 - 1);
data.setInt32(4, 256 * 256 - 1, Endianness.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
socket.add(typedData)
```

When receiving data from a socket the data delivered on the `Socket` stream are the byte-chunks as delivered from the OS. You can make no predictions of how many bytes are received at the time. If you want to be able to read a specific number of bytes one option is to implement a byte reader which have a method like this:

```dart
Future<List<int>> read(int numBytes);
```

This byte reader can then be initialized with a stream of `List<int>` and handle the framing. What you could do is have a buffer (maybe use [`BytesBuilder`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.BytesBuilder) from `dart:io`) which collect data as it is received. When `read` is called the `Future` completed when enough bytes are available. Such a byte reader can also pause the stream when the amount of buffered data reaches a certain limit and resume it again when data is read.