# Streaming text in Dart with Redstone/Shelf

Tags: dart, dart-shelf, redstone.dart

It just occurred to me that it would make sense to stream strings, each representing an element from a database query instead of returning the whole list of them at the end of the process, this might get the first result earlier on the browser. So I tried to implement this with `Redstone` which uses `Shelf`. Here is my basic test

```dart
@app.Route ('/testStream')
testSream ()
{
    StreamController<String> controller = new StreamController<String> ();

    () async
    {
        var initialTime = new DateTime.now();

        await new Future.delayed (new Duration (seconds: 1));
        controller.add("hello\n");

        await new Future.delayed (new Duration (seconds: 10));
        controller.add("chao\n");

        var finalTime = new DateTime.now().difference(initialTime);

        controller.add(finalTime.toString());

        controller.close();

    }();

    Stream<List<int>> intStream = controller.stream.map((s) => s.codeUnits);

    return new shelf.Response.ok (intStream);
}
```

Just for some context, the Linked-in guys use "text streaming" in a pattern they got from Facebook to render parts of the page quickly and insert some latter (as its available), they implement this in Playframework (Scala) where they use `Enumerables` which seem behave just like Dart streams. You can see it in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4b1XLka0UIw).

The problem with my code is that while I expected it to show `"hello"` after **1 second**, and `"chao"` **10 seconds** later. What I get is **11 seconds** of waiting and then the complete text. As you see, I am responding a `Shelf.Response` with a `Stream<List<int>>` where each `List<int>` is just a the string from the original stream converted into bytes.

Is this a Shelf problem/feature, or is Redstone messing around with the response and converting it to a future? Is there any work around?

**EDIT**

**What I want to get**

Nothing for 1 second.

After 1 second

```dart
hello
```

After 11 seconds

```dart
hello
chao
0:00:11.009000
```

**What I really get**

Nothing for 1 second.

After 11 seconds

```dart
hello
chao
0:00:11.009000
```

Comment: Isn't this a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081144

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not quite. My problem is that the browser doesn't receive ANY data util the stream closes. I want it to receive data any time the stream gets data.

Comment: Can this work with HTTP? If you use WebSocket you get this for free.

Comment: Don't think so, I don't need bidirectional communication. Also, Linked-in people used it on normal HTTP GET requests to render their page.

Comment: Honestly I don't know. Let's see if other comments provide more insight.

Comment: I know in Java they have some Stream HTTP Response thing (from JSR 353), maybe you could check that out.

Comment: I'm surprised that doesn't work. I had planned to try something similar at some point. Have you tried adding the interest codes directly to your controller to avoid the map step. Just in case the map is not behaving as you expect

Comment: @Anders, It was a shelf issue and it has been fixed, but you have to enable this as an option. I really don't use shelf directly and I haven't tried the solution as to give you any advice.

Comment: @Cristian Garcia can you point to a place where it was fixed/changed?

Comment: For those reading this -- https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf/issues/54

Answer (score 0):

For those who get here later:

As @Pacane suggested in the question comment, the link (https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf/issues/54) he posted does contain a comment by Andersmholmgren that works for the issue:

```
return new Response.ok(counterStream, context: {"shelf.io.buffer_output": false});
```

Setting the "shelf.io.buffer_output" option to false disables Shelf's output buffer and make bytes added to response stream directly sent over the network to client.